# The command removes the role from everyone who owns it

Tags: discord.py

I want a command to remove the role from everyone who owns it. I tried like below and it doesn't work. Can anyone help me.
`

```
@commands.command()
async def keyall(self, ctx):
        guild = ctx.guild
        role1 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="test1")
        role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="test2")
        role3 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="key 3")
        roles = {role1, role2, role3}
        for user in guild.members:
            for role in roles:
                if role in user.roles:
                    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

`

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Can you show us the error and full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `guild.members`, you can use `role.members`. So the command only ranged for member who had that role. For those documentation you can check [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role%20members#discord.Role.members)

```
@commands.command()
async def removerole(self, ctx):
    role_name_list = ['role1', 'role2', 'etc..']
    for role_name in role_name_list:
        role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role_name)
        for member in roles.members:
            await member.remove_roles(role)
```